# Uncaught TypeError when trying to access object values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, key, key-value

I am trying to check if a word is not in my word list but keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') at handleKeyup

I have one file bigwords.js with:

```
var words = [
    {"id": 1, "word": "abbreviate"},
    {"id": 2, "word": "bamboozled"},
    {"id": 3, "word": "calculator"},
    {"id": 4, "word": "disrespect"}
]
```

and an if statement that checks if the word does not exist in the object.

```
if (!(words.includes(currentGuess))) {
    document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = "Word not in dictionary";
    console.log('word not contained in dictionary')
    return
  }
```

I have tried several ways to write this without using .includes but no luck. I want it to execute the code if currentGuess does not equal one of the words in the list. Thank you!

Comment: `words` is `undefined`. Please show the real code

Comment: As @Konrad has mentioned, the error says `words` variable is undefined at the point of checking it. Is it possible you haven't initialized it yet at that point? E.g., could the second chunk of code run before the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` if your array looks like the below and `currentGuess` is a string

```
const words = ["abbreviate","bamboozled","calculator","disrespect"]
words.includes(currentGuess) // true or false
```

But this isn't applicable to your array of word objects.

Instead, use `find`, `some` or `filter` like below logic to check if `currentGuess` matches any `word` value inside each object in the `words` array

```
words.find(w => w.word === currentGuess)
// or
words.some(w => w.word === currentGuess)
// or
words.filter(w => w.word === currentGuess).length > 0
```

Example:

```js
const words = [
    {"id": 1, "word": "abbreviate"},
    {"id": 2, "word": "bamboozled"},
    {"id": 3, "word": "calculator"},
    {"id": 4, "word": "disrespect"}
]

const checkWord = (currentGuess) => {
  if (!(words.find(w => w.word === currentGuess))) {
    // not found
    document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = "Word not in dictionary";
    console.log('word not contained in dictionary')
  } else {
    // found
    document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = "Word in dictionary";
    console.log('word contained in dictionary')
  }
}

checkWord('disrespect');
// checkWord('random');
```

```html
<div id="tip"></div>
```

P.S. your error could relate to the `words` array not accessible in your scope as @Konrad pointed out. But sharing above the search condition regardless.